# Svn commit changes ip

Tags: svn, ip, external

I've got an svn server set up, reachable within our network under "svn.mydomain.at". the svn is also used from one user outside of our network reachable under its public ip.

the problem: 
when the outside user commits new files to the svn, and i try to update my solution the svn trys to update from the public adress instead of using svn.mydomain.at

Any tips what i've done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the problem has been solved, it was a fault by the developer who pointed to the external ip by setting the external properties

Comment: Roland, you might want to consider answering the question yourself along with some details and accepting it.

Comment: @RolandMayerhofer you mean the svn:externals property? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html